# How to create property alias of Loader in QML?

Tags: qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I'm using `Loader` that `Loader.item` has property `enabled`. Now, I want to access the `enabled` outside of Loader, so I hope that

```
property alias enabled: loader.item.enabled // error 
Loader {
    id: loader
    sourceComponent: ItemDelegate {
    }
}
```

Using `property bool enabled: loader.item.enabled` won't meet my requirement, because change `enabled` outside of `Loader` will not update `loader.item` correspondingly.

I also tried `Binding` like this, but it cannot work either.

```
id: control
property bool enabled: false
Loader {
    id: loader
    sourceComponent: ItemDelegate {
    }
    Binding {
        when: loader.status === Loader.Ready
        control.enabled: loader.item.enabled
    }
    Connections {
        target: control
        function onEnabledChanged() { // Duplicate method name: invalid override of property change signal or superclass signal
            loader.item.enabled = control.enabled
   }
}
```

Comment: First of all, don't use `enabled` as a property name as you're overlap with a default property. Every `Item` has already an [`enabled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#enabled-prop) property by default. Please explain better what you want. Your code is showing something that you apparently don't want, so it is missleading.

Comment: @iam_peter In my practical case, I have to override `enabled` property, because `sourceComponent` is an `ItemDelegate` and when its `enabled` is set to `false`, the `enabled` of its child item will be set to `false` at the same time, which is what I don't desire.
Put aside this issue, I just wonder how to create a connection between `control.enabled` and `loader.iem.enabled`.

Comment: You can't make an alias to properties within loader.item because loader.item doesn't exist at the time of the binding. It gets loaded dynamically and could have its value changed later. You could reassign sourceComponent to another delegate, or even null. What would happen to the alias in that case?

Comment: @JarMan I know, but is it possible to achieve my goal?

Comment: You could do something like `property alias myItem: loader.item`, and then when you want to set it, just make sure it's not null: `if (myItem) { myItem.enabled = true; }`

Comment: What is it that you're creating that you need a `Loader`? In just about any problem I've seen that was being solved with a `Loader` it was ultimately deemed (a) unnecessary, (b) there were better alternatives. Please provide more details to the problem you're solving.

Comment: @StephenQuan I'm writing a reusable component. The reason why I want to use Loader is because I want its sourceComponent to be specified by the user as a parameter.

Comment: Btw, is it possible to prevent the "enabled" property of "Item" in "ItemDelegate" from being forcely set to "false" when "ItemDelegate.enabled" is set to "false"?

Comment: @Kamichanw we all know how to write reusable components. Using `Loader`, is very opened ended. I would hope that your use case can be narrowed down somewhat. Else, I could also say that I am just going to call `Qt.createQmlObject()` since, I want a component I want the user to give me a magic set of requirements as a string prompt and use AI/ChatGPT to rewrite the code in a clever way with additional interfaces.